# TinyMCE html encoding and decoding - Angular Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, character-encoding, tinymce, decoding

I'm having problems with encoding and decode the text in the tinyMCE directive. I've created an own directive using the tinyMCE. I have an onRender function and onModelChange function.

This is the code of my onRender function:

```
onRender(): void {
        this.model = this.ngModel.$viewValue;


        this.ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
            return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
        });

        this.ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
            return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
        });
```

And this the code for the watch:

```
onModelChanged(newValue: any, oldValue: any): void {
        if (newValue == oldValue)
            return;

        this.ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
    }
```

When my editor is empty and I type some value in it, it gives me back this format: "&ltp&gttest&lt/p&gt", I removed the ; otherwise stackoverflow formatted the string.

This encoded text is what I need because I want to save the data as encoded HTML. When I save my page and reloads it, this will show in my text-editor: <'p'>test<'/p'>(again using '' to escape the tags) and it should show me the formatted HTML without the tags.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Thank you,
Brent

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by using this code in the onRender()

```
this.model = return $('<div/>').html(this.ngModel.$viewValue).text();
```